# Can't read from stdin in process spawned via QProcess::execute

Tags: qt, qprocess

Example code

```
int main(int, char * argv[]) {
    QString input = QTextStream(stdin).readLine();
    QTextStream(stdout) << input << "\nWe need to go deeper...\n";
    return QProcess::execute(argv[0]);
}
```

Test run

```
./test 
level 1<Enter>
level 1
We need to go deeper...
level 2<Enter>
```

and nothing going on...

PS. system() works, but will require to write code to correctly escape command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using execvp() instead of QProcess::execute().

Comment: Or, platform-independent: Create QProcess instance, use start() instead of execute().